# Selecting "Run as administrator" in the right-click context menu works, but setting it in the compatibility tab doesn't

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2010

I require the file

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\VSLauncher.exe
```

to automatically run as administrator, otherwise I cannot open *.sln files from Windows Explorer.

I had addressed this problem previously by checking the "Run as Administrator" check-box in the file property's compatibility tab, however this no longer works. Opening `VSLauncher.exe` directly does nothing, but right clicking it and selecting "Run as Administrator" does! All my `devenv.exe` are set to run as admin and they work as expected.

It's worth noting that this broke after some updates, possibly Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1.

Comment: Is "Run as Administrator" set for all users or just you?

Comment: I think, why can't you open .sln files without admin permissions ist the more interesting question. Maybe this can be solved more easy.

Comment: @Michael - Normally I would agree, but in this case, it is Visual Studio he is talking about. There are many cases where VS has to be opened with admin privileges during development.

Comment: This has been [discussed before](http://superuser.com/q/23462/2182), but not specifically dealing with VS2010 SP1.

Comment: This behavior seems kinda strange to me, I'm using vs2010 on win7 x64 pro since it was released and I don't have any problem like this.
To work around the problem, is there a way to start vs as admin via batch file?

Comment: wullxz: I have tried setting it both ways (for all users and just me.)

Comment: Jared, I have applied this exact solution previously, it doesn't seem to work any more. The SP1 install could just be a coincidence. It feels like a broken registry setting, as if the "Run as Administrator" check-box does nothing. Selecting Run as administrator from the context menu works as expected though. Really bizarre.

Comment: I'm seeing this exact behavior, and it seemed to be post-VS2010-SP1 for me as well. VS2010 `.sln` files open fine, although`VSLauncher does take it's time about opening them. VS2005 `.sln` files do nothing at all (a quick spin of the wait cursor if you're lucky). I have all devenv's and VSLauncher set to run as Administrator on Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Getting Visual Studio 2010 SP1 to run elevated when launching .sln files](https://www.re-motion.org/blogs/mix/2011/05/03/getting-visual-studio-2010-sp1-to-run-elevated-when-launching/) :

> After some research, I found that the
>   reason for Windows ignoring my
>   compatibility setting was that
>   VSLauncher.exe now had a manifest
>   embedded, which contained the
>   following fragment:
>
> ```
> <requestedPrivileges>
>    <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false">
>    </requestedExecutionLevel>
> </requestedPrivileges>
> ```
>
> So, VSLauncher.exe now specified that
>   it always wanted to be run at the same
>   execution level as its invoker. And,
>   since of course the program must know
>   better than the user, this caused
>   Windows to ignore my own execution
>   level setting.
>
> And now, to the solution. Since
>   Windows wouldn’t let me override what
>   the program said it wanted, I needed
>   to override what the program said it
>   wanted.
>
> To do that, I used the Manifest Tool
>   that comes with the Windows SDK (and
>   thus with Visual Studio):
>
> ```
> mt -inputresource:"VSLauncher.exe" -out:VSLauncher.exe.manifest
> ```
>
> This command extracted the manifest
>   from VSLauncher.exe into a file called
>   VSLauncher.exe.manifest. I then edited
>   the manifest to request the desired
>   execution level:
>
> ```
> <requestedPrivileges>
>    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false">
>    </requestedExecutionLevel>
> </requestedPrivileges>
> ```
>
> Then, I could write back the manifest:
>
> ```
> mt -outputresource:VSLauncher.exe -manifest VSLauncher.exe.manifest
> ```
>
> With the desired result.
>
> One note of caution: Please make a
>   backup copy of VSLauncher.exe before
>   manipulating the manifest. 
> And perform
>   at your own risk.

Comment: It still doesn't work for me.

Comment: opening from the recents list still doesn't open VS in admin mode. (right click VS pinned icon and pick a recent project)